# How would native english speakers do in a Proficiency exam?

Tags: language, language-exams

Everyday I get more surprised about the native language level of people. It looks like the habit of everyday talking tends to negatively bias their language level.

I’ve seen around some similar questions, but they are not exactly what I’m asking. We may also find a clue if we check a nation’s education level, but a high level exam is more restrictive than a basic education test.

Let’s suppose we are talking about USA, how would USA inhabitants do when they face a Proficiency exam or any of similar level?

Comment: Usually native speakers and proficient speakers who are not natives have pretty much different sets of weaknesses and strengths. Natives went through the so-called "critical period" and experienced "imprinting" (there's a wikipedia article about it), so they have a more intuitive feel about the language, making their speeches more fluid. Meanwhile, proficient speakers are capitalizing on crystalized knowledge (they depend on memory), speech is more mechanical and less fluid, but sometimes more technically accurate.As a result it is not unheard of for natives to be outperformed on formal tests.

Comment: ...but this does not mean everyday talking negatively biases the level, imho. It's just a different way of learning, leading to different outcomes. Even if the native is outperformed on a formal test, chances are he's still much more proficient than the non-native. Many tests are flawed because they are too mechanical to capture true language proficiency.

Comment: @Evariste - You raise many good points. Please consider converting your comments into an answer -- comments are designed to seek clarification from the asker, and are not intended to be retained permanently.

Comment: I agree. These statements made me take a deeper look at the is scenario. Although not an answer, still useful. Thank you very much